# Docker container not starting Gunicorn web server with non-privileged user

Tags: docker, gunicorn, web2py, debian-stretch

I am trying not to use root inside my Docker container, but Gunicorn is not starting.

```
FROM python:2.7

RUN apt update && \
 apt install -y  python-pip gcc python-dev libpq-dev && \
 pip install --upgrade pip && \
 pip install gunicorn && \
 pip install eventlet && \
 pip install psycopg2

RUN addgroup [username_group] && \
useradd -rm -d /home/[home] -s /bin/bash -g [username_group] -G sudo -u 1000 [username] # uid taken from host system

# USER [username] # if this line is un-commented it doesn't work.

COPY ./web2py /home/[home]/web2py

WORKDIR /home/[home]/web2py

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80 -w 3 wsgihandler
```

This is the output

```
[container]  | [2019-01-28 20:21:58 +0000] [6] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[container]  | [2019-01-28 20:21:58 +0000] [6] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[container]  | [2019-01-28 20:21:59 +0000] [6] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[container]  | [2019-01-28 20:22:00 +0000] [6] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[container]  | [2019-01-28 20:22:01 +0000] [6] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[container]  | [2019-01-28 20:22:02 +0000] [6] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[container]  | [2019-01-28 20:22:03 +0000] [6] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 80)
```

Using the same UID as the host has solved permission issues I was having with volumes. But as I can't use sudo in a Dockerfile I am not sure how to get the server running without leaving the container using root.

Comment: That error message looks like something is trying to make an _outbound_ connection, and 0.0.0.0 isn't a useful IP address for outbound connections.  Nothing you've shown in the question is obviously doing that, though; it might be something in your code.

Comment: I think it is Gunicorn trying to listen on Port 80 for any incoming connections but the user doesn't have the rights. So it is denied access to the port. I then have an Nginx Proxy in another container which sends the requests through. I haven't even tried to set that up without using root.

Answer (score 3):

I was receiving this error in a Kubernetes cluster running on EKS after upgrading 1.23 to 1.24.

The issue was migration between `dockershim` and `containerd`, where `dockershim` allowed binding on port 80, and `containerd` did not, unless an additional flag was specified (`--sysctl net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=0`). (Similar to [this issue](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/2516).)

According to the `containerd` team ([here](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/2516#issuecomment-416143805)), the bug is that `dockershim` shouldn't have been allowing binding to that port *without* the flag in the first place.

In my case, I resolved the issue by changing the port to a non-80 port, and let our Ingress controller handle routing to the new port. I would guess you could set the mentioned flag (and not update the port used) and resolve the issue that way.